# use angular observable to communicate variable changes

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to use Observable for first time, and am thoroughly confused. There are so many little examples out there and each one does some different. In a nutshell, here is what I'm trying to do:
I have a settings component that allows the user to modify the settings used in the app. Using local storage to save them, and I am able to modify them, save them, read at startup etc. Settings working great.
But now I want to be able to know when those settings have changed in real time so I can change some of the DOM (e.g.title) based on the new settings. Right now I'm trying to implement an observable from my settings service back to app.component (where title is display) so I can update title as soon as its changed. But I can't even get thy syntax right. Here is the settings.service code:

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { AppSettings } from '../shared/app-settings';
import { APPSETTINGS } from "../shared/defaultSettings";
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LOCAL_STORAGE, StorageService } from 'angular-webstorage-service';
import { LogService } from 'src/app/services/app-log.service';


@Injectable()
export class AppSettingsService {

  @Input()
  defaultSettings = APPSETTINGS;
  settings: Observable<AppSettings>;
  newSettings: AppSettings;

  constructor(    private logger: LogService,
                  @Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: StorageService) {
    this.settings = this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');
    if ( this.settings === null ) {
      this.storage.set('TRACS3_SETTINGS', this.defaultSettings);
      this.settings = this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');
    }

  }

  public getSettings(): any {
    //return this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');
    //return this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS').asObservable();
    let settingsObservable = new Observable(observer => {
      return this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');
    })
  }

  public saveSettings(settings: AppSettings): void{
    this.newSettings = settings;
    this.storage.set('TRACS3_SETTINGS', settings);
  }
}
```

and the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatIconRegistry } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AdalService } from 'adal-angular4';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { AppSettings } from './shared/app-settings'
import { AppSettingsService } from './services/app-settings.service';
import { APPSETTINGS } from './shared/defaultSettings';
import { LogService } from 'src/app/services/app-log.service';

import {LOCAL_STORAGE, WebStorageService} from 'angular-webstorage-service';

import { Aircraft } from "./shared/aircraft";
import { Content } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/r3_ast';
import {TitleService } from './services/title.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  className: string;
  aircraft: Aircraft[];
  isAuthenticated$:         Observable<boolean>;
  settings: AppSettings;
  defaultSettings: AppSettings;



  constructor(
    private titleService: TitleService,
    private appSettingsService: AppSettingsService,
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private adalService: AdalService,      
    private logger: LogService,
    private _wing: Observable<string>,
    @Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: WebStorageService
        ){
    this.settings = this.appSettingsService.getSettings();

    adalService.init(environment.config);

    this.appSettingsService.getSettings().subscribe(newSettings => this.settings = newSettings);
  } 

  ngOnInit(){
    this.className = this.constructor.toString().match(/\w+/g)[1];

    this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
    this.logger.debug(this.className, "adal userInfo: ",     this.adalService.userInfo);

    this.settings = this.appSettingsService.getSettings();

    this.logger.log(this.className, "Settings at startup: ", this.settings);
    if (this.settings.wing == null )
      this.settings = this.defaultSettings;
    _wing = this.settings.wing;
  }

  login() {
    this.adalService.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.adalService.logOut();
  }

  get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated;
  }

}
```

The entire project is up on github at https://github.com/cpeddie/TRACS3.git

Does anyone have a simple example of how to use an observable?

Thanks....

Comment: basically you have to subscribe from the component where you want to listen for the settings changes.here is a example http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject.

Comment: I guess what you written was not a review edit but a comment :) I used pseudo-code here and there. I will edit the service part

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppSettingsService {

    // Use of BehavioirSubject. This is where you post values into
    private _settings$: BehaviorSubject<AppSettings> = new BehaviorSubject(APPSETTINGS)
    // Settings observer. This is where you read from outside
    settings$: Observable<AppSettings> = this._settings$.asObservable()

    constructor(private logger: LogService,
                @Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: StorageService) {
       var settings = this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');

       if ( settings !== null ) {
           this._settings$.post(settings);
       } else {
           this.storage.set('TRACS3_SETTINGS', APPSETTINGS);
       }
    }

    public saveSettings(settings: AppSettings): void{
        this._settings$.next(settings)
        this.storage.set('TRACS3_SETTINGS', settings);
    }
}
```

The idea behind BehaviorSubject (_settings$) is that you post values onto it and observe changes on the other public settings$ observable.

Every time you modify values on the BehaviorSubject via post() the public observable fires.

This way you don't even need a getSettings() method, because you subscribe to settings$ in your component.

Answer (score 0):

## Code mechanics

The issue with your code is that in your `GetSettings()` method in your service, you *do* construct the Observable, but you *do not* return it...

```
public getSettings(): any {
   //return this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');
   //return 
   this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS').asObservable();
   let settingsObservable = new Observable(observer => { 
       return this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');
   })
}
```

> add `return settingsObservable;`

Therefore in your component constructor, you are not subscribing to the Observable *instance* you are creating in the service.

```
this.appSettingsService.getSettings().subscribe(newSettings => this.settings = newSettings);
```

## RxJS mechanics

An Observable can be created in many different ways (from values, arrays, events, etc. etc.). Bottom line is that there are two sides to the observable: publish/send/create and subscribe/receive/read.

You've found the latter in your component, using the `subscribe()` method which is available on all observable *types*. The former however, is only available on specific other observable types which add more functionality.

What you'll need to use is a **subject**. This allows you to publish messages (of changed settings) to this subject using the `next()` method. Subscribers to the observable will then receive the appropriate messages based on what type of subject it is and how it behaves... For a list of the different subject types refer to: http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html